# Do versions of android varies from manufacturer?

Tags: android

I'm very curius about one thing:

Is it possible that for instance, Jelly Bean on HTC differs from Jelly Bean on Samsung, or Sony, Motorola..etc? If "YES" why?

Actually this IS programming question because, some apps that i'm testing are working on HTC, but not (not fully working, or with "bugs" ) on Samsung, or vice versa.

Comment: If you are taking about the Android sdk/api. They should all be the same. But manufacturer may add-on extra api on their own, e.g. Samsung has S-Pen sdk. But they won't change the behavior of the original api.

Comment: I've had applications that ran perfectly on 4.0 on Samsung, but the same application was acting up on HTC phones. I guess they alter some code. This is similar to why the Note II has a lockscreen that can be bypassed. http://www.gottabemobile.com/2013/03/22/samsung-galaxy-note-2-lock-screen-bypass-secured-by-lookout-mobile/

Comment: Anyone can install a custom android os on any phone. The android from htc differes from the same version of android on samsung, but in the developer console there should be a list of supported devices, i.e. devices that passed compatibility tests from google. At least this is how it was awhile ago. So if the devices are on the list, the app should act just like in the emulator, of course except for the shortcuts of hard buttons or so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible that for instance, Jelly Bean on HTC differs from Jelly Bean on Samsung, or Sony, Motorola..etc?

Absolutely.

> If "YES" why?

Because they can. Android is open source software, meaning that anyone can modify it as they see fit.

Devices that legitimately have the Play Store app on them must meet [certain compatibility criteria](http://source.android.com/compatibility/index.html), including [passing a test suite](http://source.android.com/compatibility/cts-intro.html) designed to ensure that the Android APIs are not horribly broken.

Answer (score 2):

Although any "Jelly Bean" version is based on the same ASOP core there are a bunch of reasons why things could differ. The inclusion of Google Mobile Services (on Nexus7 for instance, but not Kindle Fire), chipset level changes that are developed by TI or Qualcomm etc to support the hardware platform as well as customizations and optimizations my OEMs and ODMs (eg a custom launcher or inclusion of Dolby Digital to the audio pipeline) are going to mean potentially different behaviors, though mostly they should not change core API functionality

Within any given major release there are also fixes and changes for the point releases which may show up in your tests.

Do you have examples of the sorts of things  you are seeing

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because some companies all vary, and it takes time to get the next Android Version into their devices. Say for instance when Android 5.0 Key Lime Pie comes out this May, Motorola will be the first to have it with the Motorola X, but it will take other companies such as LG some time to get to it. My LG Android device doesn't even go to Android 3.0 Honeycomb yet.

Comment: @rootpanthera Oh, sorry, I didn't know that.